# Terraform find s3 bucket by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to find s3 bucket by tag?

Let's assume that I've created an bucket: `12345-bucket-54321` and I added a tag (`bucket:mypersonalbucket`).

Is it possible to find this bucket in Terraform by tag?

I'm looking for something similar to:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html#filter

Answer (score 4):

Currently (04/26/19) it is not possible to get an S3 bucket by tag. If you look at the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_object.html) when attempting to get an s3 bucket as a data source you can only perform lookup by the bucket name i.e.

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "selected" {
 bucket = "bucket_name"
}
```

One thing you might want to do is open a feature request with the Terraform AWS Provider on [Github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws) requesting this functionality.